# Restart rundeck via a job

Tags: rundeck

We have a job who restarts rundeck , however during it's execution the job fail in timeout because we lose rundeck for some time due to it's booting.
Is there a way to have a job in rundeck that restart rundeck itself withoutfalling in error ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to reload the config using the Live Configuration Refreshing feature (only for Rundeck Enterprise) take a [look](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#live-configuration-refreshing-enterprise) (the feature includes the LDAP password via `rundeck.security.ldap.bindPassword` parameter). Without this, the job always fails because you're "killing" the process that runs the job (Rundeck).

Comment: Thank you @MegaDrive68k for this information. Unfortunately we have the community only, but i found a solution, i schedule with the command 'at' the restart of the service.

Comment: Hi, Good approach!